# Is there a way to define a hook in a for?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, reducers

For ever more optimisation / common logic, I want to make a good `useSelectors` that uses multiple useCallback.

Here `useSeletors` is to make selectors (like in redux) on `useReducer`.
So this is my code :

```js
const useSelectors = (state, selectors) => useMemo(
    () => selectors.map(selector => 
        (...args) => (selector(state, ...args))
    ), 
    [state]
);
```

What I wanted to do is :

```js
const useSelectors = (state, selectors) => useMemo(
    () => selectors.map(selector => useCallback(
        (...args) => (selector(state, ...args))), 
        [state]
    ), 
    [state]
);
```

Which is actually causing an error.
I probably can do this :

```js
const useSelectors = (state, selectors) => useMemo(
    () => selectors.map(selector => selector(state)), 
    [state]
);
```

But I lose the possibility to use a arguments to my selector function.
Maybe it isn't a problem, because there is something that I don't understand yet, about `useCallback` :
If I use a `useCallback` without giving arguments but in giving a dependecy, it will almost be like a variable.
At the first time I call it, is it executed ? Next times (without updating the dependency), I directly get the return of the function without execution ?

So what would happen if I put variable arguments (a counter for example) in the callback ?
Will it probably re-executed the function with this new argument even if the dependency doesn't change ?
So did the `useCallback` structure become useless with arguments ?

The last point, that I want to ask, is : when a callback is executed?
For a `useMemo`, the function is executed the first time at is declaration ? (Or the first time we use its variable ? => The difference is not really important for this case.)
Did `useCallback` is called a first time only when it is called with `()` in the code or at its declaration ?
Example :

```js
const myVar = useMemo(() => 5+5, [dependency]); // executed
const myFunc = useCallback(() => 5+5, [dependency]);

myVar; // 10
myFunc(); // executed => 10

myVar; // 10
myFunc(); // 10
```

So if it works like this it's better to call `useCallBack` in the `useMemo`, to execute the selector only when it is call and not at the mount in my third solution.
This is the main reason why I want to use multiple `useCallbacks` in my hook, without knowing the number.

[EDIT]

Second proposition with useCallback has no sens because :

```js
const test = useCallback(() => {
        console.log('test is executed');
        return 'test';
    }, [state]);
    console.log(test());
    console.log(test());
```

Logs :

test is executed
test
test is executed
test

And not that I expected :

test is executed
test
test

So it couldn't do better than the first

Answer (score 0):

`useCallback` returns a function. When one of the dependency of that hook (for example, some counter) is changed `useCallback` invoked again and return new function. It does because the function passed to `useCallback` doesn't know that the counter is changed until `useCallback` re-executes it again.

`useMemo` works the same but it returns a value. In theory you can implement `useCallback` using `useMemo`, returning function instead of value. I mean `useCallback(fn, deps)` is the same as `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`.

You can read more about it in the React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

In your code you should use `useMemo` and don't use `useCallback` inside `useMemo` because you'll get an error and it doesn't unnecessary because it uses when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders. It isn't your case. Your first example of code is correct.

Comment: I already read the doc but I probably overestimated useCallback